# android app not able to get GPS until phone restarts

Tags: android, gps, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean, ota

I am getting multiple reports from users that they can't get GPS or location services in my app until they restart their phone, and then everything works no problem.

I only get a limited sample of android users complaints, from the set of users that use my apps but it seems shockingly similar to this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39745

Google OTA updates rolled out to some additional carriers last week. Looking through my code changes over the last several months, I haven't changed any GPS/positioning stuff except in cases where I had to use the new google maps, but I can't tell if my particular user complaints are coming from a very old version or an upgrade from a very recent version or whatever version.

It appears to be related to Android 4.2 but I can't confirm that either, except the similarity of users restarting their phone and everything magically solves itself. I don't consider this a valid troubleshooting option though for my users.

Basically wondering if anyone else has solved this in code, and also putting it here in case other developers can relate to this

Comment: Were you able to debug this issue?

Comment: nope! @13hsoj I even added logic to simply not run GPS/positioning services if there was no network available, yet the phones always pass this test (because thats not the issue) and the GPS still acts wonky

Comment: I have had issues with this as well, works perfect on my Galaxy Nexus but I have personally seen that for a Galaxy Note 2 and HTC EVO 4G LTE they required a restart, and then everything worked fine. The issues occured on Android 4.1.2. I never found a cause, and every time I tried to replicate it, it failed. It was like trying to find the Loch Ness Monster, always a few steps behind.

Comment: @13hsoj I replaced all my positioning code with Google Play Services' positioning code

Comment: @mattcoker I replaced all my positioning code with Google Play Services' positioning code

Comment: @CQM Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @mattcoker https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html this is closer to what google maps uses too now